# How to display field label and field items on the same line when the item is multi-line?

Tags: css

I want to display a list of countries:

**Countries:** Angola, Botswana, Burundi, Comoros, DR Congo, Djibouti, Egypt, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Kenya, Lesotho, Libya, Madagascar, Malawi, Mauritius, Mozambique, Namibia, Rwanda, Seychelles, South Africa, Sudan, Swaziland, Tanzania, Uganda, Zambia, Zimbabwe.

But when I try to do it, I get the following result

**Countries:**

Angola, Botswana, Burundi, Comoros, DR Congo, Djibouti, Egypt, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Kenya, Lesotho, Libya, Madagascar, Malawi, Mauritius, Mozambique, Namibia, Rwanda, Seychelles, South Africa, Sudan, Swaziland, Tanzania, Uganda, Zambia, Zimbabwe.

However, if the country list fits on one line it works fine:

**Countries:** Angola, Botswana, Burundi

How can I fix that ? Here is the code

```
<div class="field field-type-list-text field-label-inline clearfix">
  <div class="field-label">Country:</div>
<div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even"><div class="textformatter-list">Algeria, Angola, Benin, Botswana, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cameroon, Cape Verde, Central African Rep, Chad, Comoros, Congo, Congo {Democratic Rep}, Djibouti, Egypt, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Ethiopia, Gabon, The Gambia, Ghana, Guinea Conakry, Guinea-Bissau, Ivory Coast, Kenya, Lesotho, Liberia, Libya, Madagascar, Malawi, Mali, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mozambique, Namibia, Niger, Nigeria, Rwanda, Sahrawi Arab Dem. Rep., Sao Tome &amp; Principe, Senegal, Seychelles, Sierra Leone, Somalia, South Africa, Sudan, Swaziland, Tanzania, Togo, Tunisia, Uganda, Zambia and Zimbabwe</div></div>
  </div>
```

```
.field-label, .field-label-inline .field-items {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.field-label, .field-items, .field-item, .textformatter-list {
    display: inline;
}​
```

This works.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KkyTw/)